# offline program to obtain HTML IMAGE MAP

Tags: html, image-editing

I've been asked to edit an html page and add image mapping to it.
So far the only thing I have in mind is opening the image in paint, find coordinates, add to the html page the following code:

```
<img src="planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">

<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="sun.htm" alt="Sun">
  <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" href="mercur.htm" alt="Mercury">
  <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" href="venus.htm" alt="Venus">
</map>
```

Can someone suggest an offline program that I can use to achieve this task? finding coordinates manually is a long process.

Comment: I'm just curious, how do you expect a software application to *know* which co-ordinates you need? There is going to be a manual process to define the areas regardless. You could try an [image map generator](https://www.image-map.net/).

Comment: yes there is a manual process. i need an offline tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use offline software to obtain imagemap like LibraOffice and there are some other software as well, here is the list of these software

1)LibreOffice

2)GIMP

3)X-Map

4)Mcc HTML Mapper

5)Handy Image Mapper

There are more software as well,use what suits you more.